# Semantic UI: How to set up a list of values onto a dropdown using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dropdown, semantic-ui

I am trying to show a list of names within a dropdown programatically using javascript based on the documentation provided at https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/usage, as indicated in the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

let list = [{'name': 'A 1'}, {'name': 'B 2', 'selected': true}, {'name': 'C 3'}];

$('#dd1').dropdown({'values': list});

});
```

However the list of names doesn't get shown whenever I click on the dropdown - the full code can be viewed on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j8utcteg/6/).

How to set up a list of values onto a dropdown using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you're trying is only available after 2.2.12. However you're using a previous version on your fiddle.

Updated fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/n0of5td1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let list = [
        { name: 'A 1', value: 'A 1' },
        { name: 'B 2', value: 'B 2', selected: true },
        { name: 'C 3', value: 'C 3' }
    ];

    $('#dd1').dropdown({ values: list });
});
```

Comment: The element 'B 2' doesn't get autoselected. Why?

Comment: Got it. Thanks :)